# Find words in string surrounded by "[" and "]":

Tags: java, android, string, split

I need help with a simple task in java. I have the following sentence:

> Where Are You [Employee Name]?
>   your have a [Shift] shift..

I need to extract the strings that are surrounded by `[` and `]` signs.

I was thinking of using the `split` method with `" "` parameter and then find the single words, but I have a problem using that if the phrase I'm looking for contains: `" "`. using `indexOf` might be an option as well, only I don't know what is the indication that I have reached the end of the `String`.

What is the best way to perform this task?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Scanner base solution

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift..");
    for (String s; (s = sc.findWithinHorizon("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])", 0)) != null;) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

output

```
Employee Name
Shift
```

Comment: this uses regex as well? what would be a better solution? what is the difference between Scanner and Pattern/Matcher solutions?

Comment: Yes. But as you noticed all answers are about Patter / Matcher. I just wanted to show an alternative way. BTW it's looks shorter

Comment: I dont think so. Scanner is Pattern / Matcher based. No difference. Maybe Scanner version is more flexible, eg instead of String input you can put there File or InputStream from a Socket...

Comment: Actually your answer gave me the best result. all the other options included the "[" and "]" in the result. Yours didn't. So I'm accepting your answer. Thanks.

Comment: could you please only explain this phrase: "(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])"? how it should be read?

Comment: it's regex with look-ahead and look-behind constructs. means find a substring with "[" prefix and "]" postfix expr. regex are difficult but useful. find some tutorial and train, train...

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev +1 for Scanner. I don't think you need such advanced regex constructs as look-aheads and look-behinds for this.

Answer (score 13):

Try with regex `\[(.*?)\]` to match the words.

`\[`: escaped `[` for literal match as it is a meta char.

`(.*?)` : match everything in a non-greedy way.

Sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift.");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: could you provide a sample code of how to use it. I have never used regex before.

Comment: @EmilAdz: is it really that hard to search for "java regex tutorial" on the internet?

Comment: @NoobUnChained you might want to add a small explanation about the regex.

Comment: The result of this includes the "[" and "]" as part of the string is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: The first group will include the [ ], but the second and third groups will not. The first group is the whole match, while each subsequent group is just the parts in parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go Java regular expression that extract text between two brackets ***including white spaces***:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="[ Employee Name ]";

    String re1=".*?";   
    String re2="( )";   
    String re3="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 1
    String re4="( )";   
    String re5="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; // Word 2
    String re6="( )";   

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String ws1=m.group(1);
        String word1=m.group(2);
        String ws2=m.group(3);
        String word2=m.group(4);
        String ws3=m.group(5);
        System.out.print("("+ws1.toString()+")"+"("+word1.toString()+")"+"("+ws2.toString()+")"+"("+word2.toString()+")"+"("+ws3.toString()+")"+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

if you want to ignore white space remove `"( )";`

Comment: That's a very complicated way to write [\\w ]*

Answer (score 1):

Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (I assume you don't need synchronization).

As you suggested, `indexOf()` using your square bracket delimiters will give you a starting index and an ending index.  use substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - 1) to get exactly the string you want.

I'm not sure what you meant by the end of the String, but `indexOf("[")` is the start and `indexOf("]")` is the end.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much the use case for a regular expression. 
Try `"(\\[[\\w ]*\\])"` as your expression.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[[\\w ]*\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Where Are You [Employee Name]? your have a [Shift] shift..");

if (m.find()) {

    String found = m.group();
}
```

What does this expression do?

- First it defines a group (...)
- Then it defines the starting point for that group. \[ matches [ since [ itself is a 'keyword' for regular expressions it has to be masked by \ which is reserved in Java Strings and has to be masked by another \
- Then it defines the body of the group [\w ]*... here the regexpression [] are used along with \w (meaning \w, meaning any letter, number or undescore) and a blank, meaning blank. The * means zero or more of the previous group.
- Then it defines the endpoint of the group \]
- and closes the group )